# Delphi7 - How to extract information about SSE from JvComputerInfoEx1 component?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, sse, jvcl

Information in form1.JvComputerInfoEx1.CPU.SSE is stored as TSSESupports.
My question is how data is actually stored in TSSESupports and how to convert to plain string?

The [wiki page](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvCPUInfo.SSE) is not very helpful in this matter.

Comment: Yeah, JEDI documentation usually does not exist. Have you looked at the source. That's how you are expected to work these things out.

Comment: I've found this in JclSysInfo.pas

`type
  TSSESupport = (sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4A, sse4B, sse5);
  TSSESupports = set of TSSESupport;`

Comment: So you know what to do then?

Comment: Use the `in` operator to test whether or not each enum value is in the set `SSE`. Do you understand Delphi sets?

Comment: I'm reading this now 
http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=set

I think I will be able to get what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the JCL sources.

```delphi
type 
  TSSESupport = (sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4A, sse4B, sse5); 
  TSSESupports = set of TSSESupport;
```

So, TSSESupports is a set. Values in a set are stored bitwise.
You can test if a value is in set by "in" operator.

```
var
  Value: TSSESupports;
begin
  if sse in Value then
    ShowMessage('Supports SSE');
end;
```

But the easiest way of converting a set into a string is using RTTI function "SetToString"

```
uses System.TypInfo, JclSysinfo;

var
  Value: TSSESupports;
  pTI: PTypeInfo;
  S: string;
begin
  pTI := TypeInfo(TSSESupports);
  S := SetToString(pTI, Word(Value));
  ShowMessage(S);
end;
```